# Aibo API not redirecting to my redirect uri after authentication

Tags: javascript, api, sony

I'm trying to create an aibo linkable app.  I have a node.js/express app running and when I receive a request for '/' I redirect to the aibo authentication endpoint with appropriate parameters.  When I go to my site it correctly displays the SONY sign in page and I can log in with my email and password but it takes me to the myaibo.aibo.com site instead of redirecting to my '/auth' endpoint.

Here is a short snippet of what I'm doing:

```
const CLIENT_ID = process.env.AIBO_CLIENT_ID;
const CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.AIBO_CLIENT_SECRET;
const REDIRECT_URI= 'https://aibo.jonfleming.net/auth';

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  if(!req.session.authenticated) {
    req.session.state = randomGenerate(12);
    const url = `https://myaibo.aibo.com/account_link.html?state=${req.session.state}&` +
    `client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&scope=pub&redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}&response_type=code`;

    res.redirect(url);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

app.get('/auth', (req, res) => {
  const code = req.query.code;
  const state = req.query.state;

  if (state === req.session.state) {
    // request access token
    // get deviceId
    // update header
    req.session.authenticated = true;
    res.send('Connected');
  }
});
```

The '/auth' endpoint never gets hit.

I've also tried displaying a clickable link in place of the res.redirect(url).

```
res.send(`<html><body><a href="${url}">Sign In</a></body></html>`);
```

Clicking the link has the same result.  It takes me to the sign in page but never redirects back to my app.